# Projection Matrix for Pseudo Cylindrical Projection

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, projection, projection-matrix

Imagine having a mixed group of 3D objects contained within a sphere, and your goal is to create a [cylindrical equal-area projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_cylindrical_equal-area_projection) of the entire scene. Using OpenGL, you might think to stitch together multiple render target textures (4 to be exact) from rotating a camera about the central axis, and then correct for radial distortion in a post-processing shader since you are projecting onto a plane instead of a cylinder. Ideally, you'd be able to sweep the camera's frustum through the entire volume of the sphere without any overlap, and such that each render fills the entire pixel space of the rectangular texture (as cylindrical projections do).

So, just for clarity, here is a visualization of the spherical scene (which has objects contained within), and a camera frustum that spans PI / 2 about the Y-axis. 
[image: Visualization of a cylindrical projection camera frustum]

Notice that the 'far' plane is reduced to a line, which is collinear with the sphere's Y-axis. The white intersecting lines that form an "X" on the outer face of the frustum represent the camera's origin, or (0,0,0) in eye-space. This outer face is also the 'near' plane, located 0 Z-units away from the camera.

The idea is that the sphere's central axis projects rays outwards such that all rays travel parallel to the Y-plane (i.e., the plane having normal (0, 1, 0)), and each ray emanating from the sphere's **origin** intersects the sphere's surface at a perpendicular angle.

## My question:

Naively, I think that an OpenGL projection matrix can do this -- as far as I understand, the projection I am going for here is linear and therefore possible? However, I can't seem to solve the equations properly:

> let `s` be the radius of the sphere.
>
> So, in *eye-space*, from the camera's origin:
>
> - the left and right edge of the near plane are located at `-s` and `s` units along the X-axis, respectively
> - the top and bottom edge of the near plane are located at `s` and `-s` units along the Y-axis, respectively
> - the left and right edge of the far plane are co-located at `-s` units along the Z-axis (keep in mind that in eye-space, Z values are negative in front of the camera)
>
> In the OpenGL projection matrix:
>
> - `-w_c < x_c < w_c`
> - `x_n = x_c / w_c`
>
> Since the left and right frustum planes converge in front of the camera, I solved for an equation that maps my inputs to their expected outputs and concluded that:
>
> - `x_n = x_e / (z_e + s)`
>
> Which means that `x_c = x_e` and `w_c = z_e + s`. 
> This fills in two rows on my projection matrix:
> [image: yea]
>
> ---------- **This is where I get stuck** ----------
>
> It's clear that `y_n` does not depend on `x_e` or `z_e` at all, and that its equation should be:
>
> - `y_n = y_e / s`
>
> This is akin to an orthographic projection. However, this introduces a conflict with the `w_c` I already solved for in the `x_n` equation.

I derived my projection matrix above by following steps from [this article](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html), which succinctly explains the derivation of the perspective and orthographic projection matrices for OpenGL.

It *appears* that I may be encountering the limits of a linear transformation? **If this indeed is non-linear**, then I don't understand why and would appreciate an explanation  :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your projection require `y = sin(phi)` the mapping is non-linear.

Theoretically, with a 4x4 matrices (together with homogeneous coordinates), you can describe affine transformations which is a bit more expressive than a linear transformation. Affine transformations have the form `a * x + b` where a and x are vectors and b is a scalar value. There is no way how can express trigonometric functions with that.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate a spherical projection, the [Azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) angle has to be projected to the Y coordinate of the viewport. This is the angle of the vector to the projection of a point in the XZ plane in view space. The [Altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) angle has to be projected to the X coordinate of the viewport. This is angle between a vector to point in view space and the XZ plane of the view space. The length of the vector to the point has to be projected to the depth.

[image]

Since the angles have to be calculated by the arcus sine this cannot be done by a projection matrix.
The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. It transforms from eye space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates. The NDC are in range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1). With this it is possible to describe a simple [Rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), but not an [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).
(See further [How to render depth linearly in modern OpenGL with gl_FragCoord.z in fragment shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh/45710371#45710371) not [Transform the modelMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008171/transform-the-modelmatrix/46008573#46008573))

[image]

The following vertex shader shows how to calculate a spherical projection, the center of the projection to the viewport is defined by the view matrix:

```
in vec3 inPos;

uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;
uniform vec2 u_depthRange;

const float cPi = 3.141593;

void main()
{
    vec4  viewPos = u_viewMat44 * u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
    vec2  dirXY   = normalize( vec2( -viewPos.z, viewPos.x ) );
    vec2  dirZ    = normalize( vec2( length(viewPos.xz), viewPos.y ) );
    float posX    = asin( abs( dirXY.y ) ) * 2.0 / cPi;
    float posY    = asin( abs( dirZ.y ) ) * 2.0 / cPi;

    gl_Position = vec4(
        0.5 * sign( dirXY.y ) * mix(2.0-posX, posX, step(0.0, dirXY.x) ),
        sign( dirZ.y ) * posY,
        2.0 * (length(viewPos.xyz)-u_depthRange.x) / (u_depthRange.y-u_depthRange.x) - 1.0
        1.0 );
}
```

**Note, this shader has an big issue. If a primitive reaches from an azimuth angle near 180° to an azimuth angle near -180°, then the primitive will not reach to the borders of the viewport. The primitive will be drawn across the entire viewport.**

See the following WebGL example which demonstrates the shader and the issue:

```js
glArrayType = typeof Float32Array !="undefined" ? Float32Array : ( typeof WebGLFloatArray != "undefined" ? WebGLFloatArray : Array );

function IdentityMat44() {
  var m = new glArrayType(16);
  m[0]  = 1; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  = 0; m[3]  = 0;
  m[4]  = 0; m[5]  = 1; m[6]  = 0; m[7]  = 0;
  m[8]  = 0; m[9]  = 0; m[10] = 1; m[11] = 0;
  m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 0; m[15] = 1;
  return m;
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Translate( matA, trans ) {
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i )
        matB[12+i] = matA[i] * trans[0] + matA[4+i] * trans[1] + matA[8+i] * trans[2] + matA[12+i];
    return matB;
}

function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
function Normalize( v ) {
    var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
    return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
}

var Camera = {};
Camera.create = function() {
    this.pos    = [0, 0, 0.0];
    this.target = [0, -1, 0];
    this.up     = [0, 0, 1];
    this.fov_y  = 120;
    this.vp     = [800, 600];
    this.near   = 0.5;
    this.far    = 100.0;
}
Camera.Perspective = function() {
    var fn = this.far + this.near;
    var f_n = this.far - this.near;
    var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
    var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = t/r; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  =  0;                              m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0;   m[5]  = t; m[6]  =  0;                              m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0;   m[9]  = 0; m[10] = -fn / f_n;                       m[11] = -1;
    m[12] = 0;   m[13] = 0; m[14] = -2 * this.far * this.near / f_n; m[15] =  0;
    return m;
}
Camera.LookAt = function() {
    var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
    var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
    var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
    var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
    var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
    var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = mx[0]; m[1]  = my[0]; m[2]  = mz[0]; m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = mx[1]; m[5]  = my[1]; m[6]  = mz[1]; m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = mx[2]; m[9]  = my[2]; m[10] = mz[2]; m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = tx;    m[13] = ty;    m[14] = tz;    m[15] = 1; 
    return m;
} 

var ShaderProgram = {};
ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
            return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.attribIndex = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.attribIndex[name] = gl.getAttribLocation( progObj, name );
        }
        progObj.unifomLocation = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.attribIndex[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.UniformLocation = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.unifomLocation[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShaderProgram.SetUniformI1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1i( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1f( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF2  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform2fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF4  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM33 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript) {
      source = "";
      var node = shaderScript.firstChild;
      while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) source += node.textContent;
        node = node.nextSibling;
      }
    }
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : 0;
} 
ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : 0;
}

var VertexBuffer = {};
VertexBuffer.Create = function( attributes, indices ) {
    var buffer = {};
    buffer.buf = [];
    buffer.attr = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++ i ) {
        buffer.buf.push( gl.createBuffer() );
        buffer.attr.push( { size : attributes[i].attrSize, loc : attributes[i].attrLoc } );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i] );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attributes[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    }
    buffer.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    buffer.inxLen = indices.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    return buffer;
}
VertexBuffer.Draw = function( bufObj ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i ) {
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i] );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    }
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i )
       gl.disableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
}

        
function drawScene(){

    var projection = document.getElementById( "projection" ).value;

    var canvas = document.getElementById( "glow-canvas" );
    Camera.create();
    Camera.vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    var currentTime = Date.now();   
    var deltaMS = currentTime - startTime;
        
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.enable( gl.CULL_FACE );
    gl.cullFace( gl.BACK );
    gl.frontFace( gl.CCW );
    
    // set up draw shader
    ShaderProgram.Use( progDraw );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_projectionMat44", Camera.Perspective() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_viewMat44", Camera.LookAt() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF2( progDraw, "u_depthRange", [ Camera.near, Camera.far ] );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1( progDraw, "u_projection", projection )
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3( progDraw, "u_lightDir", [-1.0, -0.5, -2.0] );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1( progDraw, "u_ambient", 0.2 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1( progDraw, "u_diffuse", 0.7 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1( progDraw, "u_specular", 0.8 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1( progDraw, "u_shininess", 10.0 );
    var modelMat = IdentityMat44()
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 10.0 ), 2 );
    modelMat = Translate( modelMat, [0.0, -2.5, 0.0] );
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 13.0 ), 0 );
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 17.0 ), 1 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_modelMat44", modelMat );
    
    // draw scene
    VertexBuffer.Draw( bufTorus );
}

var startTime;
function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( currentTime, intervall ) {
    return Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
function CalcMove( currentTime, intervall, range ) {
    var pos = self.Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0
    var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
    return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
}    
function EllipticalPosition( a, b, angRag ) {
    var a_b = a * a - b * b
    var ea = (a_b <= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( a_b );
    var eb = (a_b >= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( -a_b );
    return [ a * Math.sin( angRag ) - ea, b * Math.cos( angRag ) - eb, 0 ];
}

var sliderScale = 100.0
var gl;
var progDraw;
var bufCube = {};
var bufTorus = {};
function sceneStart() {

    document.getElementById( "projection" ).value = 0;
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "glow-canvas");
    var vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progDraw = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ],
      [ "u_projectionMat44", "u_viewMat44", "u_modelMat44", 
        "u_lightDir", "u_ambient", "u_diffuse", "u_specular", "u_shininess", ] );
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inPos" );
    progDraw.inNV  = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inNV" );
    progDraw.inCol = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inCol" );
    if ( progDraw == 0 )
        return;

    // create torus
    var circum_size = 32, tube_size = 32;
    var rad_circum = 1.0;
    var rad_tube = 0.5;
    var torus_pts = [];
    var torus_nv = [];
    var torus_col = [];
    var torus_inx = [];
    var col = [1, 0.5, 0.0];
    for ( var i_c = 0; i_c < circum_size; ++ i_c ) {
        var center = [
            Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i_c / circum_size),
            Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i_c / circum_size) ]
        for ( var i_t = 0; i_t < tube_size; ++ i_t ) {
            var tubeX = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i_t / tube_size)
            var tubeY = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i_t / tube_size)
            var pt = [
                center[0] * ( rad_circum + tubeX * rad_tube ),
                center[1] * ( rad_circum + tubeX * rad_tube ),
                tubeY * rad_tube ]
            var nv = [ pt[0] - center[0] * rad_tube, pt[1] - center[1] * rad_tube, tubeY * rad_tube ]
            torus_pts.push( pt[0], pt[1], pt[2] );
            torus_nv.push( nv[0], nv[1], nv[2] );
            torus_col.push( col[0], col[1], col[2] );
            var i_cn = (i_c+1) % circum_size
            var i_tn = (i_t+1) % tube_size
            var i_c0 = i_c * tube_size; 
            var i_c1 = i_cn * tube_size; 
            torus_inx.push( i_c0+i_tn, i_c0+i_t, i_c1+i_t, i_c0+i_tn, i_c1+i_t, i_c1+i_tn )
        }
    }
    bufTorus = VertexBuffer.Create(
      [ { data : torus_pts, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos },
        { data : torus_nv,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inNV },
        { data : torus_col, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inCol } ],
        torus_inx
    );

    startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval(drawScene, 50);
}
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 inPos;
attribute vec3 inNV;
attribute vec3 inCol;

varying vec3 vertPos;
varying vec3 vertNV;
varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform mat4  u_projectionMat44;
uniform mat4  u_viewMat44;
uniform mat4  u_modelMat44;
uniform vec2  u_depthRange;
uniform float u_projection;

const float cPi = 3.141593;

void main()
{
    vec3 modelNV  = mat3( u_modelMat44 ) * normalize( inNV );
    vertNV        = mat3( u_viewMat44 ) * modelNV;
    vertCol       = inCol;
    vec4 modelPos = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
    vec4 viewPos  = u_viewMat44 * modelPos;
    vertPos       = viewPos.xyz / viewPos.w;
    
    vec2 dirXY    = normalize( vec2( -viewPos.z, viewPos.x ) );
    vec2 dirZ     = normalize( vec2( length(viewPos.xz), viewPos.y ) );
    float posX    = asin( abs( dirXY.y ) ) * 2.0 / cPi;
    float posY    = asin( abs( dirZ.y ) ) * 2.0 / cPi;
    vec3 prjPos = vec3(
        0.5 * sign( dirXY.y ) * mix(2.0-posX, posX, step(0.0, dirXY.x) ),
        sign( dirZ.y ) * posY,
        2.0 * (length(viewPos.xyz)-u_depthRange.x) / (u_depthRange.y-u_depthRange.x) - 1.0 );
    gl_Position   = mix( vec4( prjPos.xyz, 1.0 ), u_projectionMat44 * viewPos, u_projection );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vertPos;
varying vec3 vertNV;
varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform vec3  u_lightDir;
uniform float u_ambient;
uniform float u_diffuse;
uniform float u_specular;
uniform float u_shininess;

void main()
{
    vec3 color      = vertCol;
    vec3 lightCol   = u_ambient * color;
    vec3  normalV   = normalize( vertNV );
    vec3  lightV    = normalize( -u_lightDir );
    float NdotL     = max( 0.0, dot( normalV, lightV ) );
    lightCol       += NdotL * u_diffuse * color;
    vec3  eyeV      = normalize( -vertPos );
    vec3  halfV     = normalize( eyeV + lightV );
    float NdotH     = max( 0.0, dot( normalV, halfV ) );
    float kSpecular = ( u_shininess + 2.0 ) * pow( NdotH, u_shininess ) / ( 2.0 * 3.14159265 );
    lightCol       += kSpecular * u_specular * color;
    gl_FragColor    = vec4( lightCol.rgb, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<body onload="sceneStart();">
    <div style="margin-left: 520px;">
        <div style="float: right; width: 100%; background-color: #CCF;">
            <form name="inputs">
                <table>
                    <tr> <td> projection </td> <td>
                        <select id="projection">>
                            <option value="0">spherical</option>
                            <option value="1">perspectiv</option>
                        </select>
                    </td> </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 520px; margin-left: -520px;">
            <canvas id="glow-canvas" style="border: none;" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```