# What's the fourth dimension in a GLSL gl_Position?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, perspectivecamera

I'm learning OpenGL, and currently I'm writing a shader, but I'm confused as to why the `gl_Position` variable is a `vec4` instead of a `vec3`, as I'd expect. I'd expect this of course because it uses 3D space, not 4D.

I hope I'm at least right in assuming that the first three fields of `gl_Position` are indeed the x, y, and z ordinates of the position.

In case my question isn't clear enough: what's the fourth field of `gl_Position`.

By the way, I'm using OpenGL 3.2 and GLSL 1.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gl_Position`is a  [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). At [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) the 4th component `w` is 1. As a result of a [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection), the component assumes another value than 1.

`gl_Position` can be transformed to a [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in normalized device sapce by a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide).

```
vec3 ndc = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w;
```

`gl_Position` is the clip space coordinate. In clip space the clipping of the scene is performed.
A point is in clip space if the `x`, `y` and `z` components are in the range defined by the inverted `w` component and the `w` component of the homogeneous coordinates of the point:

```
-w <=  x, y, z  <= w.
```

See also [Transform the modelMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008171/transform-the-modelmatrix/46008573#46008573)